# How to GROUP BY Multiple Columns and COUNT in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I want to group 3 columns (Fruit, Color & Vendor) and get their corresponding group count in excel, without using any VBA code, but just simply using Excel functions.

**Fruit Vendor Ledger Table**:

| ID | Fruit | Color | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Red | Rocket Apples |
| 2 | Apple | Red | Rocket Apples |
| 3 | Apple | Yellow | Rocket Apples |
| 4 | Apple | Green | Rocket Apples |
| 5 | Apple | Green | Rocket Apples |
| 6 | Apple | Green | Rocket Apples |
| 7 | Apple | Green | Sweet Greens |
| 8 | Apple | Green | Sweet Greens |
| 9 | Orange | Orange | Tangerines |
| 10 | Orange | Orange | Tangerines |
| 11 | Orange | Orange | Tangerines |
| 12 | Banana | Yellow | Phils |
| 13 | Banana | Yellow | Phils |
| 14 | Banana | Green | Brighton |
| 15 | Banana | Green | Brighton |
| 16 | Banana | Green | Brighton |

**Expected result**:

| Fruit | Color | Vendor | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Red | Rocket Apples | 2 |
| Apple | Yellow | Rocket Apples | 1 |
| Apple | Green | Rocket Apples | 3 |
| Apple | Green | Sweet Greens | 2 |
| Orange | Orange | Tangerines | 3 |
| Banana | Yellow | Phils | 2 |
| Banana | Green | Brighton | 3 |

In T-SQL, I would have written the SQL Query as follows. I wanted to know the function or feature by which I could achieve the same in Excel.

```
SELECT [Fruit], [Color], [Vendor], COUNT(1)
FROM [dbo].[FruitVendorTable] WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [Fruit], [Color], [Vendor]
```

Comment: use a pivot table.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I thought Pivot doesn't give you one single row for each group but rather creates like multiple levels, one for each column. Unless you can share a screenshot of we can use Pivot and still have all 3 columns in a single level.

Comment: you mean like this: https://imgur.com/a/znntUQk

Comment: Just turn off the subtotals and Grand totals, then show in tabular form and repeat values.

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. How do I turn off the subtotals and grand totals?

Comment: Easy with Pivot Tables as mentioned by @ScottCraner Sir, to turn off the subtotals goto --> Design Tab --> Left Corner in the Ribbon, Subtotals --> **Do Not Show Subtotals**

Comment: When you select on of the cells in the pivot table you get the ability to open the Design tab.  It is in there.

Comment: Perfect. It was actually 2 things for me. First is **Subtotals --> Do Not Show Subtotals** and the second was **Report Layout --> Show in Tabular Form**. Thank you @ScottCraner & MayukhBhattacharya. Much appreciated.

Comment: @GaryTheBrave btw I have posted an alternative using formulas in answers you can give a try. but yes pivot table will be easy here.

Comment: Thanks @MayukhBhattacharya. I actually needed a Pivot table solution. I keep wanting to do quick GROUP BY clauses but never was able to get a similar looking result from SQL in Excel. But now thanks to you two, I was able to. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the answer, on behalf of @ScottCraner and @MayukhBhattacharya. Thank you both!

1. Pivot the Table
2. Design Tab > **Subtotals** > **Do Not Show Subtotals**
3. Design Tab > **Reports Layout** > **Show in Tabular Form**
4. Design Tab > **Reports Layout** > **Repeat all Item Labels**

[image: Pivot Table results]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps with Excel Formulas try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=LET(
    α, B2:B17 & "|" & C2:C17 &
        "|" & D2:D17,
    UNIQUE(
        HSTACK(
            B2:B17,
            C2:C17,
            D2:D17,
            MMULT(
                N(
                    TOROW(α) =
                        α
                ),
                SEQUENCE(
                    ROWS(α),
                    ,
                    ,
                    0
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

---

- Using `LET()` function makes easier to read as well define variables, thus improving performance and reduces the use of redundant calculations.
- `α` variable is defined for the concatenated columns of `B` , `C` and `D`, this created so as we can use in the following logic of our functions.
- Using `MMULT()` function to return the matrix product of two arrays, the first one is the comparison of the `α` with the same `α` which is now converted into a single row, which returns `TRUE` and `FALSE` for the match and non matched ones. using the `N()` function we are converting it into a `1` and `0` so as the `MMULT()` can understand, the other array being the one returned using `SEQUENCE()` & `ROWS()` function. Ultimately this will give us number of counts for each corresponding groups.
- Finally, using `HSTACK()` we merge all the three columns and the one returned using above into one array. Since it will have duplicate groups with respective counts, therefore using `UNIQUE()` to exclude them.

---

When the above answer was posted, the `GROUPBY()` and `PIVOTBY()` function was not launched in `MS365` Office Insiders version, but if its enabled now, then can use as shown below as well:

```
=GROUPBY(B2:D17,B2:B17,ROWS,,0)
```

---